# What's the fastest way to export all excel add-in modules to .bas files?

Tags: vba, module, export, excel-addins

I'm working on an big excel-addin with many modules. I need to export them to .bas file to manage them with SVN. I know a hot key to export them fast, **Ctrl+E**. But the number of my modules is too many that I still lose too much time to export them.
Does anyone know a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great tool which should do what you need

http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

From their website:

> Export Code Files - This feature allows you to export all the code files from a project to the directory you specify without the need to perform a project cleaning.

If you are having trouble locating the menu option, see the above page for information:

> You must set your security to trust access to Visual Basic projects in order to use the code cleaner.
>
> In Excel 2007 the code cleaner can only be run from the VBE Tools menu. There will be no option to run the code cleaner from the new Excel 2007 Ribbon user interface.

Comment: Like @Davuz, I also cannot open the `VBA Code Cleaner` dialog as the manual (website/help file after installed). Please guide us on Excel 2010/2007. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you contact the creator of the utility if you find it's not working for you...

Comment: @NamG.VU Follow the link and look at the bottom of the page at `Version-Specific Notes`. See if that helps.

Comment: The tool is only applied to Excel 2007. Thank you @JimmyPena and Tim Williams