# Snapshot of data structures, VBA excel

Tags: vba, serialization, excel, error-handling, snapshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the fastest way to export all excel add-in modules to .bas files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362404/whats-the-fastest-way-to-export-all-excel-add-in-modules-to-bas-files)

Is it possible to do snapshot of all used modules and data structures in VBA Excel and recover it some time after?

The reason is reproducing error after crashes

ADDED. Yes, in essence I want to serialize classes and types.

Comment: Do you want to export modules so you can import them later and look at them?

Comment: How about going for a simple solution: creating a button that performs a Saveas? Click the save button to save, click your own created export button to create the backup.

Comment: Are you wanting to capture the state of your program after an error? Like the call stack?

Comment: @JimmyPena:  yes, exactly. For example, I'd like export them to file..

Comment: @Kim Gysen: I have very rich structures with many field, I don't want to save each field separately - I just want to save current state of data

Comment: @Brad: yes, I'd like to have possibility to do debug after importing of saved data

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11473126/190829

Comment: @JimmyPena, sorry for misunderstanding, but I want to export values of all data, not the text of modules.. But this link is very interesting anyway

Comment: I feel like what you kind of want is to serialize all your classes as they are to an XML file? I know this function exists in other languages but VBA might not have it as it is. (I'm sure you could force something)

Comment: @Brad, yes, exactly, as one of possible ways

Comment: As far as I know there is not a way to do this with any built in functions. I've wanted to do this before too but have not actually accomplished it. If you were using VSTO that's another story. The C# environment offers this this natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel like what you kind of want is to serialize all your classes as
> they are to an XML file? I know this function exists in other
> languages but VBA might not have it as it is. (I'm sure you could
> force something) – Brad
>
> @Brad, yes, exactly, as one of possible ways – nikaan

Assuming that this method does not exist for VBA (although it is available for VB.NET or VB 2005: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315703), I would probably try to make a simulation: Write the state of each object / variable (of those needed) to a txt file by using FSO.
I don't know if this is feasible for your project though and I probably wouldn't like to do this with pleasure for a huge amount of code.

```
dim sFile               As string 
Dim FSO                 As FileSystemObject     
Dim FSOFile             As TextStream 


sFile = "U:/Log.txt"

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FSOFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, 2, True) 
FSOFile.writeline (<Descriptions+Property/variable value>) 
FSOFile.Close
set FSO = nothing
```

Depending on how well you input descriptions (eg. inlcuding boolean values for successful instantiation of objects, etc...), you may be able to see what has happened behind the screen up to the point where your application crashed...
I don't know if this answers your question, as I'm a little bit doubting about what you refer to with "fields" (comments).

Answer (score 1):

When being the owner of a VBA project, you can create a sub routine that exports all the modules in your currenct project. 
This link provides the code:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Application_Framework/ExportVBACode.htm

For the purpose as you describe it, I don't see a reason to do this.
Personally I would use a lame trick like this one:

Option Explicit

```
Sub Save_File()

Dim sCur_Path           As String
Dim sCopied_Path        As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


sCur_Path = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sCopied_Path = "U:/Copied_New.xlsm"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs sCopied_Path
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs sCur_Path

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! but this routine copies only sheets and text of modules, not the current state and values of every field..

Comment: I'm sure you know http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/SourceTools.aspx  It does something like that but it is not what I want

Comment: @nikaan Understood, I didn't catch that initially.