# Screenshot of VBA editor in debug mode in terminal, or use Excel DOM to find error line and desc in VBA editor?

Tags: c#, excel

An Excel workbook is called by a command line, which itself is launched from c# (3.5). The workbook runs, but there is an error in the VBA. For example, a column is missing in a pivot and Excel prompts the user with an error message, with the option to "debug".

From the process in C#, we can detect that the error window is open, and we take a screenshot of the error message, and then we close the error box.

If this was an interactive session, Excel would then present the VBA editor, in debug mode, with the line where the error occurred highlighted.

However, because this is running in an unattended terminal session, we are then unable to take a screenshot of the VBA editor (the screenshot is a black screen).

We are then able to close the excel program, using the windows PID.

The questions is: how do we either get a screenshot of the VBA editor, or how do we bind (with COM or interop) with the Excel in debug mode, and traverse the dom to find the error line, and possibly error message?

Comment: investingating further... Will report soon. There are a lot of related questions on SO...

Comment: The guy actually doing the work isn't in the office now, will update when he gets back. Also, awarding the reputation points to A Webb.

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you have authoring control of the Excel workbook(s), you can insert line numbers and a error handler to write to file Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source, Erl.

(2) If (1) is not an option, but you can set Macro Security on the host to allow programmatic control of the Visual Basic project, then you can get the active line number:

```
Dim xl As excel.Application
Dim StartLine As Long, StartColumn As Long, EndLine As Long, EndColumn As Long
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
xl.VBE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn
Debug.Print StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn
```

(3) If neither (1) nor (2) is an option, it is a bit hairy, but you can copy out the bitmap contents of the window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution if you have access to modify the VBA code might be to use On Error GoTo and a line label. This will stop the Debug message from popping up and instead, when a runtime error occurs, execution will jump to the specified label at which point you can access the information available in the global Err object. VBA does not have the concept of a try/catch block so this is pretty much the nearest proximally.

```vb
Sub Main()
    On Error GoTo Catch

    ' Code that may trigger errors here...

   GoTo Finally
Catch:
    ' Log Err info, etc...
    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
Finally:
    ' This is always reached last (error or no error)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll look into that, although, we want to have the ability to catch the code that people forget to wrap in on error resume next/on error goto zero.

Comment: I suspected that might be a constraint... I realized that I was basically giving you a more elaborate example of A. Webb's first suggestion but it feels like the most sane choice (neglecting the constraint). The only other things I can think of are what they mentioned as well but if I think of something different I will update my answer. Excel automation on a headless box is always going to be sketchy at best.

Answer (score 1):

[Snapshot of data structures, VBA excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668189/snapshot-of-data-structures-vba-excel/11672199#11672199)

It sounds a lot like the question above in which I suggested to write the state of your code to a separate txt file (in the example, using a FileSystemObject) where you can afterwards analyze where you got stuck: 
booleans on conditions / instantiation of objects, number on succesful loops, values contained in variables, well - whatever you want...).
In combination with an error handler (as suggested before) you can see where the code stopped + code / description of the error.

A copy-paste for your sake:

```
dim sFile               As string
Dim FSO                 As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFile             As TextStream
sFile = "U:/Log.txt"   

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FSOFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, 2, True)
FSOFile.writeline (<Descriptions+Property/variable value>)
FSOFile.Close set FSO = nothing
```

I agree that it is a more work, but you'll know where to find the bug.
All depends on how hard and often you need this, in combination with how long the code is that you need to describe. Since I am not aware of your situation, I cannot judge on that.

In the end, it seems a lot of work, but actually it's quite easy since it's just describing the code that is already there.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I like it... I'll test that out too.